# Изменение ширины директивы в зависимости от контента

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, angular-material

Есть два таба. Второй не важен, а в первом отрисовывается график с помощью `dagreD3`.

После загрузки данных(ajax), выстреливается `$rootScope.$broadcast("drawGraph");`

Проблема в следующем: Родительский для директивы `graph` `<md-content>` не меняет свой размер под ширину изображения. Т.е. если изображение, допустим 2500px, то оно обрезается без добавления скролла.

При этом, если переключиться на вторую вкладку, а потом вернуться обратно, то ширина `<md-content>` меняется под размер изображения и появляется скролл.

Разметка:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height>
    <md-tab label="Граф" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
        <md-content>
            <graph></graph>
        </md-content>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Таблица" md-dynamic-height>
           тут что-то
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Директива `graph`:

```
.directive('graph', function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope   : false,
       template: '<svg id="graph" style="margin: 10px;"></svg>',
       link    : function (scope) {
           var svg      = d3.select("#graph");
           var svgGroup = svg.append("g");
           var render   = new dagreD3.render();

           scope.$on("drawGraph", function () {
               var data  = scope.data;
               var graph = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
                   .setGraph({})
                   .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function () { return {}; });

               data.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                   graph.setNode(node, {label: node})
               });

               data.links.forEach(function (link) {
                   graph.setEdge(link[0], link[1]);
               });

               render(d3.select("#graph g"), graph);

               svg.attr("height", graph.graph().height + 40);
               svg.attr("width", graph.graph().width + 40);

               var xCenterOffset = (svg.attr("width") - graph.graph().width) / 2;
               svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + xCenterOffset + ", 20)");
               scope.drawing = false;
           })
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Тут возможны причины в `css`, в `js` самого `md-content`, а также то, что `angular` не "видит", что значение внтури `md-content` изменилось. Нужен воспроизводимый пример, который бы повторял описаное поведение.